# Terraform Provider: Set taint status from within provider on update

Tags: terraform

I'm doing something really obtuse inside a custom-written provider that leverages the definition of status=tainted

I know I can use the TF CLI to taint/untaint a resource.
I also know that terraform only taints on failed create calls.

I would like to taint on updates as well.

I'm wondering if I can programmatically set taint status from within the provider, however the terraform API is a bit restrictive.

Does anyone know?

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to achieve something with a sub-optimal approach, but we would need more information to assist. Could you provide your resource schema and update method?

Comment: I can't do that, legal issues and whatnot. (sorry) 

I've written dozens of providers and am aware of terraform state lifecycles and management.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to control the taint status of a resource after it is created. Terraform just uses this tracking internally to know that a create failed and thus it needs to clean up the probably-broken object on a subsequent run.

However, tainting is just one reason why an object might need to be replaced rather than updated in a plan. Within provider code you have control over the "requires new resource" flag on particular attributes (called `ForceNew` in the SDK).

The most common way to flag "requires new resource" is to set `ForceNew` statically on a given attribute and have the SDK set the flag for you automatically if it detects that the value has changed. However, if you implement `CustomizeDiff` on your resource type then you can use whatever logic you like to make that decision, and ultimately call [`ForceNew` on the `ResourceDiff` object](https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/helper/schema#ResourceDiff.ForceNew).

Normally we'd use that to signal that a change made *by the user* requires replacement, but that's not a requirement. You can also pass the name of a `Computed` attribute there and, as long as the value of it is actually planned to change, Terraform will honor it.

If there isn't any existing attribute that is natural to represent whatever condition you have that requires replacement, you can add a new attribute that *only* signals the "healthiness" of your object, perhaps called `status`, and then if you detect that it's in a bad state during `Read` you can call `d.Set("status", "error")`. Then in `CustomizeDiff` you can check whether `status` is `"error"` and if so call `d.Set("status", "ok")` followed by `d.ForceNew("status")` to represent the transition from error status to OK status as requiring object replacement.

That should then show in the plan just like any other attribute that "requires replacement":

```
    ~ status = "error" => "ok" # requires replacement
```

...and Terraform will show it as either a `-/+` or `+/-` change depending on whether the user set `create_before_destroy`.